Is rapid IP switchting available for attackers on TCP servers?
I'm working on a server implementation and I'm wondering how quickly attackers can switch ip addresses.
I know with UDP attackers can actually just send in whatever ip address they want, but with TCP a connection will be dropped if the client doesn't respond in the handshake. (if you have a timeout configured)
I'm wondering how quickly attackers can switch ip addresses to overload a server that accepts TCP connections. I know people can switch ip addresses with a vpn, but I'm not sure on the speed. Like every second? Or every 5 minutes? Or instantly?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. It would be more on-topic at [security.se]. But in general - it very much depends on the infrastructure attackers have. But it is not unusual that they don't actually switch their own IP but the simply use (their own or rented) botnet infrastructures to allow attacks from many IP addresses, often at the same time.

Simply consider that your attacker has a bot net of thousands of compromised systems each with a different IP. As all of the bots can be remote controlled they can act like an attacker being able to "switch" the IP address.
